# automatically save the picture without confrimation using CameraCaptureUI in UWP apps

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile

I just developed sample UWP app to capture images from web cam. this is working smoothly

this is the code I have used

```
  public class CameraCaptureService : ICaptureService
    {
        public async Task<StorageFile> CapturePhotoAsync()
        {
            var dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
            dialog.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;
            dialog.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.JpegXR;
            dialog.PhotoSettings.AllowCropping = true;

            var file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

            ...

            return (file == null) ? null : file;
        }
    }
```

but once after I click **Image Capture** button 
this is awaiting until I confirm ***If I want to proceed this picture or discard the process and restart*** (with right sign and incorrect sign)
I'm trying to skip that stage and directly save this to local storage

Is this possible to do, using `CameraCaptureUI` class `PhotoSettings` ?

NB : `dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);` is async method

Comment: Currently, there is no such api for skipping image preview by within `CameraCaptureUI` class `PhotoSettings`.  If  you want to save the photo to local storage directly. you could use `MediaCapture` class. This is [official code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame) you can refer to.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT okay thanks :)